# Calling static method from type variable

Tags: java, generics

I have the class:

```
public class AbstractHandler {
    public static void handle(){ 
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented");
    }
}
```

which is going to have some number subclasses.

Also I have the following class which is going to use that class:

```
public class Consumer<T extends AbstractHandler>{

    public static void handle(){
        //I need to call the method 
        //T.handle() somehow
        //Is that possible?
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is `#handle` static anyway? Makes no sense to me, especially if you want polymorphism.

Comment: As stated by others - **static** is basically a violation of "OO concepts". One should only use it with great care; as it can make unit testing extremely hard. So besides the fact that your intended "usage" is plain wrong ... even it would somehow work: don't do it. Only make methods/objects static if there is no other way!

Comment: By the way, did you actually try calling `T.handle();`? It compiles and runs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the method is `static`, there's no need to know what exactly `T` is.

Just do:

```
AbstractHandler.handle();
```

Answer (score 2):

Static methods are not inherited.

So you have `AbstractHandler.handle`, and that does not mean every `T` shall have one too.

If they do, it is not the same method either - there is no connection between then, even if they have the same name.

Comment: *"that does not mean every T shall have one too"* But you can call a static method using the subclass, right? `class Sub extends AbstractHandler {} Sub.handle();`

Comment: @Radiodef indeed you are correct, but only when `Sub` does not redefine `handle`; it's simply a syntax sugar as I see it, because if you do declare `handle` you can't add `@Override` annotation, can't call `super.handle`, et cetera, which suggests they aren't related :)

Comment: So then why can't `T.handle()` be the same as `AbstractHandler.handle()`? ; )

Comment: I'm guessing that's because `T` is erased at runtime, and therefore there would be no way to know whether `handle` would match a child that had `handle` or the parent's version - unlike if, for example, you had a `T t` object, whose class is not erased (though `T` is), and then the method chain could be fetched normally. But your argument is good, it would make sense if it were possible.

Answer (score 1):

Since the method you plan to invoke is static, simply invoke:

```
AbstractHandler.handle();
```

... in your `Consumer#handle` method body.

I doubt this is actually what you want to do though.

You'd probably want to change the signature of `handle` as instance (i.e. not `static`), and invoke `T.handle()` in your `Consumer#handle` method body.